# Camera rotation issue on mobile with touch joystick control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a Unity game with touch joystick controls, where swiping on the screen rotates the Cinemachine Freelook camera. The camera should not rotate when moving the joystick, and this is working correctly when testing in the Unity Editor and using Unity Remote. However, after building the game and running it on an Android phone, the camera starts rotating when moving the joystick. Can anyone suggest a possible solution to this problem? Here is the code I am using for touch input and camera rotation:

```cs
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class TouchSwipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float TouchSensitivityX = 10f;
    public float TouchSensitivityY = 10f;

    public string TouchXInputMapTo = "Mouse X";
    public string TouchYInputMapTo = "Mouse Y";

    void Start()
    {
        CinemachineCore.GetInputAxis = GetInputAxis;
    }

    private float GetInputAxis(string axisName)
{
    int touchCount = Input.touchCount;
    int validTouchCount = 0;
    Touch validTouch = new Touch();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < touchCount; i++)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
        if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
        {
            validTouchCount++;
            validTouch = touch;
        }
    }
    
    if (validTouchCount > 0)
    {
        if (axisName == TouchXInputMapTo)
            return validTouch.deltaPosition.x / TouchSensitivityX;
        if (axisName == TouchYInputMapTo)
            return validTouch.deltaPosition.y / TouchSensitivityY;
    }
    
    return Input.GetAxis(axisName);
}

}
```

I have tried different types of codes to fix it, but it's the Same.